# No message got sent

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I used this code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(4800); //Baud rate of the GSM/GPRS Module
  Serial.print("\r");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+918281537478\"\r");
  //Number to which you want to send the SMS
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Test SMS -Jay\r");
  //The text of the message to be sent
  delay(1000);
  Serial.write(0x1A);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() { }
```

In the serial monitor AT commands were printed but no message was sent. Someone please help.

Comment: Maybe you need to send the messages to a GSM shield instead of your PC?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Please be sure to take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 1):

I have the same code and it's working fine. But in my code, I set my baud rate `9600` means you have to change

```
Serial.begin(4800);
```

to

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

And few question... which GSM Model you used? GMS SIM 300 or someone else. Becuase mine is GSM SIM 300. If you have someone else then maybe you have received some document with it, in that specific baud rate is defined. Just set it.

And then fist of all, check your GSM board is really working or not? Becuase I have this problem but that time my GSM module is not working. So, I replace and then everything working fine.

Put your SIM CARD on GSM and then make a call. If the buzzer is ringing that mean your GSM board working fine. Be sure about your arduino connection with GSM shield.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Serial.print is designed to print out to the serial (programming) port.

If you are seeing these commands there then that means they are not being sent to the GSM module.